# Не добавляет стили

Tags: javascript, html

Не добавляет стили

```
$('#avatars').append(avatarfull => `
    <h3>Аватар</h3>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="cell"><img src="${data.avatarfull}" /></td>
    </tr>`).join('');
```

Добавляет в дереве элементов только

```
<table id="avatars">
    <h3>Аватар</h3>
    <img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/3d/3db37f813fee6c2047a2da5b2d552aec380b51b3_full.jpg">
 </table>
```

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Причина в том, что ты добавляешь массив в DOM, а должен добавлять объект. Выведи просто в консоль и поймешь
avatarfull => `
    <h3>Аватар</h3>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="cell"><img src="${data.avatarfull}" /></td>
    </tr>`)

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте! В тэге table может быть только тэг tr, а другие теги не допустимы! Если убрать эту строку

```html
<h3>Аватар</h3>
```

то все выводится нормально